# UIGridView Selected Background color

Tags: ios, grid, cell

I am using this code for a gridview:

https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView

I want to get a background color on the table cell when pushed, till other cell is pushed. The code comes with a

```
didSelectRow
```

void but the cell is already made in an other void so I can't use simply

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]
```

in didselectrow.

Any simple ideas to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen of UIGridView it is very underpowered, capable of doing simplistic displays but not enough for what I think you might want. My suggestion to you is to take a look at [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). I've used this package in my own programs and have had tremendous success with it. It offers an increased toolset including ways of querying the currently selected index in the grid.

You could also try expanding UIGridView yourself to keep track of the selected index and methods to return the cells at the selected indices. But whatever you end up doing the answer is to have your gridview keep track of what is selected and then retain a reference to the gridview in your view controller so that you can use the information appropriately.

Comment: Is there a simple way to expand the code for adding a selected view?

Comment: My advice is to take a look at AQGridView it already wrote everything you need to do. It isn't a terrible amount of work to add it to your code, but I still would think the simplest approach is to rewrite the code to use AQGridView.